# 150K rows for scatter plot graph loading forever?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart, dundas

I have 150K records of X and Y columns and I am trying to draw a chart  for FinanicalFormula. It is taking time to create chart for ever. It is not throwing error also.

```
Chart1.DataSource = dtChart
      ' Data bind to the selected data source
      Chart1.DataBind()
      Chart1.ChartAreas(0).RecalculateAxesScale()
  Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, 
                         "Linear,,false,false", 
                         Chart1.Series("Series1"), 
                         Chart1.Series("Linear"))

  Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, 
                         "Exponential,,false,false", 
                         Chart1.Series("Series2"), 
                         Chart1.Series("Exponential"))
  Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, 
                         "IsLogarithmic,,false,false", 
                         Chart1.Series("Series3"), 
                         Chart1.Series("Logarithmic"))

  Chart1.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.Forecasting, 
                         "Power,,false,false", 
                         Chart1.Series("Series4"), 
                         Chart1.Series("Power"))
  Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 0
  'Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalOffset = 0.1
  Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.Minimum = 0
  'Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY.IntervalOffset = 0.5
```

control is coming out from these all line in debug. after that page taking to load data on the graph. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be if you can find a way to reduce the point count in your data by preprocessing it (i.e. combining several data points that are in proximity to each other to a single data point) - interestingly enough Dundas has relevant articles on their support pages:

1. [Improving performance in Dundas
   Chart with large data sets](http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=809)
2. [Grouping Data](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2005/Data_GroupingBasics.html)